# Dojo layout - two panels inside a panel

Tags: layout, dojo

I've just started learning dojo for an evaluation exercise (we may be using it at work). The timescales on project probably won't allow me to learn this from the ground up, so I'm jumping in the deep end. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction;

The below code represents a page from their tutorial;

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/dijit_layout/demo/appLayout.html

^^ What it's meant to look like.

I've got that working, but I want two panels to be in the centre section: A plain content panel at the top, and a tabs panel underneath it. The below code represents how i thought I might achieve this. What I'm finding is that if I comment out the content pane (the one with "Hello world" in) then it "takes over" its parent content pane, and the tabs panel is no longer even shown. Uncomment it, and i get my tabs back.

Is anyone able to point me in the direction of a good example of how to do this?

```
<div id="appLayout" class="demoLayout" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
    data-dojo-props="design: 'headline'">

    <div class = "centrePanel"
        data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
        data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">

            <%-- I want to uncomment this bit!!
            <div 
                data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
                data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">
                    Hello World                    
            </div>
            --%>

            <div 
                data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer"
                data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>                    
            </div>                



    </div>        
    <div class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">Header content (top)</div>
    <div id="leftCol" class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'left', splitter: true">Sidebar content (left)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest a second borderContainer inside your center contentpane (instead of the tabcontainer), with design=headline.
You can then put a ContentPane in the top section of the inner bordercontainer and the tabcontainer in the center section of the same.

This amazing tool may help you generate the proper layout : http://maqetta.org:55556/maqetta/

Just create a new HTML page, and look at the "Dojo Containers" section on the left bar...

So your example should be :

```
<div id="appLayout" class="demoLayout" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
data-dojo-props="design: 'headline'">

<div class = "centrePanel"
    data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
    data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
        <div id="innerLayout" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
data-dojo-props="design: 'headline'">

            <div 
                data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
                data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">
                    Hello World                    
            </div>


            <div 
                data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer"
                data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>                    
            </div>                

    </div>

</div>        
<div class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">Header content (top)</div>
<div id="leftCol" class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'left', splitter: true">Sidebar content (left)</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Copying/pasting the above code doesn't actually work, but it got me going in the right direction and I've managed to achieve what i was trying to! Do you know of any decent resources for learning the layout side of things? The official website seems a bit flakey.

Comment: By the way, you could also do a layout without an inner BorderContainer. Just place your TabContainer in the "bottom" region and leave the ContentPane in the "center" region.

Comment: An example here : http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/HK2NQ/36/... not exactly the same as with the inner BorderContainer, and had to switch the outer Bordercontainer's design from headline to sidebar...